# Update record column with id found in the table of an associated model

Tags: postgresql, update

Given three tables:

A `users` table with `id`'s:

```
╔════╗
║ id ║
╠════╣
║ 1  ║
╟────╢
║ 2  ║
╟────╢
║ 3  ║
╚════╝
```

A `purposes` table with `user_id`'s

```
╔════╤══════════╗
║ id │ user_id  ║
╠════╪══════════╣
║ 1  │ 2        ║
╟────┼──────────╢
║ 2  │ null     ║
╟────┼──────────╢
║ 3  │ null     ║
╚════╧══════════╝
```

Where the `user_id` can be `null`.

And a `journeys` table with `user_id`'s and `purpose_id`'s.

```
╔════╤═════════╤════════════╗
║ id │ user_id │ purpose_id ║
╠════╪═════════╪════════════╣
║ 1  │ 2       │ 3          ║
╟────┼─────────┼────────────╢
║ 2  │ 1       │ 2          ║
╟────┼─────────┼────────────╢
║ 3  │ 1       │ 1          ║
╚════╧═════════╧════════════╝
```

We want to create a PostgreSQL query that will find all of the `purposes` with `null` in their `user_id` column, select their associated `journeys` (by selecting them based on the id of said purposes), and then update the then empty `user_id` column of the purpose with the `user_id` found in the first associated journey.

What is the best way to do this?

I've gotten as far as being able to find all the `user_id`'s from the `journeys` table who have purposes with an empty `user_id` column using an `exists` subselect query but I'm unsure how to update that `null` `user_id` column with the matching `user_id` found in the `journeys` table...

```
select
   user_id
from
   journeys
where exists(
    select
       id
    from
       purposes
    where
       user_id is nil
       and purposes.id = journeys.purpose_id
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FROM` clause in the `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html). Like:

```
UPDATE purposes p
SET    user_id = j.user_id
FROM   journeys j
WHERE  j.purpose_id = p.id
AND    p.owner_id IS NULL
AND    j.user_id IS NOT NULL;  --  may be redundant
```

Ideally, you have some kind of unique index on `journeys(purpose_id)` to make this unambiguous. Else multiple rows might qualify.

The last predicate `AND j.user_id IS NOT NULL` is redundant if the column is defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Good point on the unique index. I'm expecting that the rows found in the `journeys` table with a given `purpose_id` will all have the same `user_id`. Is there a database constraint that I can use to enforce this?

Comment: @dynsne: A `UNIQUE` *constraint* would prevent duplicates. If you already have duplicates, define which row to pick from each set of dupes in a subquery. There are various techniques. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860